# Having problems with exporting a large notebook as a PDF file

Tags: export, notebooks

I have a largish notebook (300 hundred pages when printed) that I have exported to PDF in the past (version 11?). I am having trouble with this in version 12.0.  A PDF is produced (except once), but it will not display. When viewed with SumatraPDF, text does not display and graphics display with no text.  When viewed with Acrobat, nothing displays and page errors are reported. I have other (smaller) notebooks that export successfully.

Are there known problems with PDF export of notebooks? Size related?

Diagnostic hints will be welcomed.

Comment: Printing to PDF has never worked. It might be better to just take pictures of each page on the screen with your phone!